# Colors not shown in the output of git-graph

Tags: git, colors, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to use [git-graph](https://github.com/mlange-42/git-graph). I have installed it, but I cannot obtain the output I see in the screenshots. In particular when I run it with its own repository from the Gnome terminal in Ubuntu, the colours are missing:

[image]

I did not configure anything, but used it "as is". I would expect to have a more colourful output, as shown in the screenshots in the github page.

Is this a problem with the colours in the terminal?

Comment: have you tried adding `--color` or `--color=always` ?

Comment: Yes, `--color=always` leads to the same result. Using `--color=none` produces an actual b&w result. I mean, I have _some_ colours, just not the ones shown in the screenshots in the documentation. They are purple, orange and mostly grey.

Comment: I would look into issues with how your terminal interprets and renders colors

Comment: I can see at least 4 different colors in the app's output: off-white for commit logs, brighter bluish gray for tags and branches, darker bluish gray for commit IDs, and a blue arrow at the bottom left corner. I strongly suspect that you have configured your terminal emulator to use a nontraditional palette of 16 colors, such as Solarized, or something similar. What happens if you revert in the terminal's preferences to a more traditional one, such as "xterm", "rxvt" or "linux console"?